# Populate values in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new beginning, I'm writing a script using PHP, jquery. on of the forms I'm developing is to allow the users to add several records to one table. that was fine. 
my issue, I need to replicate the value of subSerId to other fields of the added rows once clientname updated, I can do it for the first two records but after that it will not work.

as you can see through the following picture, I looking for away when I update the client name field, the value of Service ID will be changed. I can have this happen for the first and second rows (parent) but not for the third.

[image]

And here is the jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxRecords= 30;
  var i=1;
  var htmlForm='<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input id="childsubSerID" disabled name="subSerID[]" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Auto" value=""></td><td><input id="childclientName" name="clientName[]" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter client name" value=""></td><td><input id="childsubSerType" name="subSerType[]" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter grand name" value=""></td><td><input id="childserCount" name="serCount[]" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter service count" value=""></td><td><input id="childsubSerDetails" name="subSerDetails[]" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter details" value=""></td><td><button id="'+i+'" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" value="X">X</td></tr>';
  $('#add_more').click(function(){
    if(i<=maxRecords){

     $('#dynamic_field').append(htmlForm);
    i++;
    }

  });
  $(document).on('click','.btn_remove', function(){
      var button_id=$(this).attr("id");
      $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
      i--;
  })  


 $("#dynamic_form").on('change','#clientName', function(){
     $('#subSerID').val(  $('#hiddenId').val() );
 });

 $("#dynamic_field").on('change','#childclientName', function(){
 $('#childsubSerID').val(  $('#subSerID').val() );
 });
});
```

Comment: Does "dynamic field" already excists in the initial load?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs, use a class instead

Comment: I updated the post with the full code. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you cannot have duplicate IDs anywhere.

Change the code to use class

You also need to navigate via closest("tr")

I added a tbody which is where you need to append

I also test the length of the tbody instead of calculating using addition and subtractions

```js
const htmlForm = '<tr><td><input disabled name="subSerID[]" type="text" class="childsubSerID form-control" required placeholder="Auto" value=""></td><td><input name="clientName[]" type="text" class="childclientName form-control" required placeholder="Enter client name" value=""></td><td><input  name="subSerType[]" type="text" class="childsubSerType form-control" required placeholder="Enter grand name" value=""></td><td><input  name="serCount[]" type="text" class="childserCount form-control" required placeholder="Enter service count" value=""></td><td><input name="subSerDetails[]" type="text" class="childsubSerDetails form-control" required placeholder="Enter details" value=""></td><td><button class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" value="X">X</td></tr>';


$(function() {
  const maxRecords = 30;
  const $tb = $('#dynamic_field');

  $('#add_more').click(function() {
    if ($tb.find("tr").length < maxRecords) { // changed to length
      $tb.append(htmlForm);
    }

  });
  $tb.on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    this.closest("tr").remove();
  })


  $tb.on('change', '.clientName', function() { // where is this?
    $(this).closest("tr").find('.subSerID').val($('#hiddenId').val());
  });

  $tb.on('change', '.childclientName', function() {
    const $parentRow = $(this).closest("tr")
    $parentRow.find('.childsubSerID').val($parentRow.find('#subSerID').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add_more">Add</button>
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dynamic_field"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you this solved my issue, big thank you to all, any suggested good resources to read on jquery/ PHP?

Comment: I do not know. I do not need it. You can always go to jquery.com

Comment: I changed one more $(document) to $tb

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not enough to see the problem, but i guess that's because you are using same id for several elements, the fact is the id of the elements must be unique and you can't have elements with the same id (which leads to error just like in your case).
try using **class** instead of id, it should solve your problem.

You updated your code and it doesn't make sense anymore!

Comment: I updated the code, with the full one. the new id for the child row is #childsubSerID

Comment: As i said in the answer you are using duplicated id name for elements which leads to some malfunctioning in selecting elements, so what you have to do is getting rid of id and using class name instead of them. (its allowed to have duplicated class names)

Comment: Thanks again, can you provide example on the code! even if you don't like the code :)

Comment: it was not the only issue... See my answer